# PHP script can't connect to Database on port 3307

Tags: mysql

I can connect to mysql just fine with my port number through the command line like so:

```
mysql -h ##.##.##.## -P 3307 -u wpuser -p
```

I have a php file that tries to connect to the DB,

```
<?php
include("/path to wordpress directory/wp-config.php");
$conn = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and I keep receiving this error:

```
Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host '##.##.##.##:3307' (1)
```

It does not seem to be able to connect to that host/port even though I successfully can through the command line.

I have tried manually writing the DB credentials in my $conn variable so i know that is not the issue.

Comment: This does not sound WordPress related.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This is connection object created to use in wordpress

```
$mydb = new wpdb( 'username', 'password', 'my_database', 'localhost' );
```

and if it is way that you want to go check in codex $wpdb function 'select' to select database when do queries. Hope it help.